# Why does ActiveRecord generated SQL includes Date for a Time column?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, time

When I create a SQL Time column I get a pure time, ie. no date. But when I use the Ruby Time class I get a date as well. The problem is when do a 'find' the generated SQL includes a date and I seem to be getting weird results.

*The Table*

```
start_date: time
end_time: time
day_of_week: string
```

*ActiveRecord*

```
def self.now_playing
    self.find(:first, :conditions => ['day_of_week = ? AND end_time > ? AND start_time < ?',  Time.now.strftime('%A'), Time.now, Time.now])
end
```

*The SQL*

```
SELECT * FROM `schedules` WHERE (day_of_week = 'Saturday' AND end_time > '2009-06-20 10:19:59' AND start_time < '2009-06-20 10:19:59') LIMIT 1
```

The SQL generated includes a date, could this be why I'm getting odd results, for example no record returned when there is a schedule for the given time? However if the column is a pure time column should MySQL not ignore the date part?

Comment: Schedule.first.end_time.class => Time
Schedule.first.end_time => Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 2000

So the date part is always 1/1/2000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time in Ruby is more like Timestamp... always has a date. ActiveSupport has built-in conversions for this, so if the date is screwing up your results, you can use #to_s(:format) to get the results you need. By default, there is a :time option, but it only returns hours / minutes (%H:%M) , if you needed seconds as well you'd have to add another format ...

Create an initializer called time_formats.rb or something and add:

#### Rails 2-ish

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!({
  :time_long => "%H:%M:%S"
})
```

#### Rails 3

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
  :time_long => "%H:%M:%S"
)
```

Then in your finder, just do like so:

```
def self.now_playing
  time = Time.now
  self.find(:first, :conditions => ['day_of_week = ? AND end_time > ? AND start_time < ?',  time.strftime('%A'), time.to_s(:time_long), time.to_s(:time_long)])
end
```

More info can be found here: http://jasonseifer.com/2010/03/10/rails-date-formats

Or here: http://brian.rarevisions.net/extending-date-formats-in-rails-3